# When to check if presenting viewController is of type if using autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, presentviewcontroller

This is the code I am using to set the constraints in viewDidLoad:

```
if (self.presentingViewController?.isKindOfClass(GameViewController) != nil) {
    print("huhu")
    self.bottomViewToBottomConstraint.constant = -367
    self.bottomViewToHiddenButtonConstraint.constant = 401
} else {
    self.bottomViewToBottomConstraint.constant = -200
    self.bottomViewToHiddenButtonConstraint.constant = 200
    print("No presenting viewController")
}
```

The message I'm getting is No presenting viewController. As you can see I am also setting constraints which will be animated differently, depending on what class is presenting viewController. So at what time it is already known who is presenting view controller and is also the right time to set the constraints? Thanks for help

Comment: Try moving your code to `viewWillAppear`

Answer (score 0):

**As simple as:**

> After you add the `bottomView` to it's `superview`.

Try viewWillAppear method:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // here
}
```